# WSO2 EI: Cannot establish connection to the endpoint

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I'm using an HTTP Endpoint in WSO2 EI 6.6 to call a external API and when I test the endpoint in the management console I get the *Cannot establish connection to the endpoint* error please help me to sort this out.

**Note:** This endpoint is working fine in other EI 6.6 server.

[image: Management Console]
[image: Log Error]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is, that the service you are trying to access doesn't have HTTP HEAD/GET method support. Hence if you do an HTTP GET or a HEAD it returns an HTTP 404.

[image]

When you click `Test` button for endpoint testing the server will typically send an HTTP HEAD request (This could be a GET, not 100% sure) to determine whether the service is available. So since both methods are not supported you are seeing the above error. You don't have to worry about this error as your service will work when you send a proper POST request.